# Laravel Transform a Collection of a certain kind of entity to another

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-5.4

I'm having trouble with the hasMany eloquent function on Laravel. Basically, there's a Model called *Element* that is structured like a graph. It's composed of an id and the next_id.

I've set a function that returns the next element on the graph.

```
public function next() {
    if($this->element_type->id == 2) {
        return $this->subelement->answers();
    } else {
        return $this->hasOne(Element::class, 'id', 'next_id');
    }
}
```

Whenever it enters the "else" statement, it works just fine. It gives me the next node of the list in terms of Element. The problem is when it meets the condition $this->element_type->id == 2

The functions I use for this case are:

On 'Element' Model

```
public function subelement() {
    return $this->hasOne(Branch::class);
}
```

On 'Branch' Model

```
public function answers() {
    return $this->hasMany(Answer::class, 'branch_id', 'id');
}
```

So 1 Element is linked to 1 Branch that is linked to many Answers. From that, what I get as a result of return $this->subelement->answers() is a Collection of 'Answer'. What I actually wanted was a Collection of 'Element', which are the nodes of the graph. But I can't figure out how to transform this whole Collection. I do have a function to transform a single element from 'Answer' to 'Element'

On 'Answer' Model

```
public function element() {
    return $this->belongsTo(Element::class);
}
```

But I can't figure out how to transform each element of the Collection to have a whole Collection of 'Elements'.

Any clues? Thank you.

Comment: should not it work ? `return $this->subelement->answers->element();` Also when you are returning in your foreach `$value->element()->get()` will also should work.

Comment: You are right about the foreach, this method does work. But when I try to return `return $this->subelement->answers->element();` it gives me _BadMethodCallException with message 'Method element does not exist._ One way I made it work, but not as I intended, was to return for one of the answers `return $this->subelement->answers[0]->element();`. But I actually wanted to return them all as 'Element'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a function in Element model like this one

```
public function convertToElement($collection){

    $col = [] ;
    foreach($collection as $ans){
        $col[] = $ans->element();
    }
    return collect($col);
}
```

And then call like `return $this->convertToElement($this->subelement->answers()->get());`

Comment: Hmm interesting! You answered my question but sadly, it doesn't work. I just realized that `$this->subelement->answers()` doesn't return a Collection. It returns an object of 'HasMany'. The reason I thought it was a Collection was whenever I used the function '->next' on tinker, it would return me a Collection. So, when I try what you proposed, it doesn't even go into the foreach loop and returns an error: `LogicException with message 'Relationship method must return an object of type Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\Relation'`. But thanks anyway, I'll try to change it!

Comment: my mistake please use get() to get the result `$this->subelement->answers()->get()` and `$ans->element()->first()`